# Immutable SQL columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ddl

Is it possible to mark a column `immutable` in MSSQL?

Seems like it would be a useful DDL feature; once a value is set in a row ('row' being defined as a specific relation of values to a primary key), it could not be changed without deletion of the row.

Obviously (like most things) this is more than doable in the application layer, but half the fun of SQL DDL is error-checking your application code.

Comment: How would you fix it if it gets set wrong?

Comment: If the user doing the DML is not the owner of the table, you could revoke the UPDATE privilege on the column. Then it can only be inserted, but no longer update (I know this is possible in PostgreSQL, but haven't tried it in SQL Server)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - seems like an answer to me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the user doing the DML is not the owner of the objects and not "db_owner" in the database itself, you can just grant "insert" privilege, but not update privilege for that table:

Assuming a table with `id, col1, col2`

```
grant insert, select, delete on the_table to the_user;
grant update (id, col2) on the_table to the_user;
```

With these grants *the_user* can insert rows and supply values for all three columns. He can also update the `id` and the `col2` column, but not the `col1` column.

The db_owner (and possibly the creator/owner of the table) can always update all columns. I don't know if there is a way to revoke that privilege from those rolws.

Answer (score 9):

It's possible, using an UPDATE TRIGGER like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterUpdateAsset ON dbo.Asset
FOR UPDATE AS
IF UPDATE(AssetTypeID) AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted i JOIN deleted d ON i.ID = d.ID WHERE i.AssetTypeID <> d.AssetTypeID)
BEGIN 
    RAISERROR ('AssetTypeID cannot change.', 16, 1);
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END
```

(Note: The table has a Primary Key column, called ID).

I'm only rejecting the update if the value of AssetTypeID changes. So the column could be present in an update, and if it specified the old value, than it would pass through. (I needed this way)

Answer (score 8):

No, there is no such feature in SQL Server.

The closest I can think about is an update trigger on the table that checks if the values in the specific column are the same for the `INSERTED` and `DELETED` logical tables and rejects the updates for the changed rows.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea and @jaraics has written the code to do it.

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge, this is not possible with DDL.  However, you could implement BEFORE UPDATE triggers to meet your requirement.  In the BEFORE UPDATE trigger, you could raise an exception or do whatever you want rather than update the row.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to deny update rights to the table and create a stored procedure (which users do have the right to execute) that does not update the immutable field.